# negative look ahead on whole number but preceded by a character(perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I have text like this;

```
2500.00 $120.00 4500  12.00 $23.00 50.0989
```

Iv written a regex;

```
/(?!$)\d+\.\d{2}/g
```

I want it to only match `2500.00`, `12.00` nothing else.

the requirement is that it needs to add the '$' sign onto numeric values that have exactly two digits after the decimal point. with the current regex it ads extra '$' to the ones that already have a '$' sign. its longer but im just saying it briefly. I know i can use regex to remove the '$' then use another regex to add '$' to all the desired numbers.

any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Note that `$` and `.` both need to be escaped!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, you need to look *before* the pos where the first digit is.

```
(?<!\$)
```

But that's not going to work as it will match `23.45` of `$123.45` to change it into `$1$23.45`, and it will match `123.45` of `123.456` to change it into `$123.456`. You want to make sure there's no digits before or after what you match.

```
s/(?<![\$\d])(\d+\.\d{2})(?!\d)/\$$1/g;
```

Or the quicker

```
s/(?<![\$\d])(?=\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d))/\$/g;
```

Comment: +1 Maybe I'm overlooking an edge case, but I wonder whether `\b` would work just as well as `(?!\d)` (it does work for the data supplied by the OP).

Comment: @FMc, `\b` will act differently than `(?!\d)` for `123.45a`. I doubt the OP cares one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky only because you are trying to include too many functionalities in your single regex. If you manipulate the string first to isolate each number, this becomes trivial, as this one-liner demonstrates:

```
$ perl -F"(\s+)" -lane's/^(?=\d+\.\d{2}$)/\$/ for @F; print @F;'
2500.00 $120.00 4500  12.00 $23.00 50.0989
$2500.00 $120.00 4500  $12.00 $23.00 50.0989
```

The full code for this would be something like:

```
while (<>) {                     # or whatever file handle or input you read from
    my @line = split /(\s+)/;
    s/^(?=\d+\.\d{2}$)/\$/ for @line;
    print @line;                 # or select your desired means of output
    # my $out = join "", @line;  # as string
}
```

Note that this split is non-destructive because we use parentheses to capture our delimiters. So for our sample input, the resulting list looks like this when printed with `Data::Dumper`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '2500.00',
          ' ',
          '$120.00',
          ' ',
          '4500',
          '  ',
          '12.00',
          ' ',
          '$23.00',
          ' ',
          '50.0989'
        ];
```

Our regex here is simply anchored in both ends, and allowed to contain numbers, followed by a period `.` and two numbers, and nothing else. Because we use a look-ahead assertion, it will insert the dollar sign at the beginning, and keep everything else. Because of the strictness of our regex, we do not need to worry about checking for any other characters, and because we split on whitespace, we do not need to check for any such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
s/(?<!\S)\d+\.\d{2}(?!\S)/\$${^MATCH}/gp
```

or

```
s/(?<!\S)(?=\d+\.\d{2}(?!\S))/\$/g
```

I think it is the shorter way.

`(?<!\S)` not preceded by a character that is not a white character

`(?!\S)` not followed by a character that is not a white character

The main interest of these double negations is that you include automaticaly the begining and the end of the string cases.

Comment: Never use `$&`. It slows down every regex without captures in the entire process.

Comment: @ikegami: I have, indeed, found old topics (2001) about this problem. Are you sure it is always actual? And are you sure that you doesn't have the same problem when you use a capturing group? (see: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=127988 ). However, you always have the possibility to avoid this potential problem using : `s/(?<!\S)(?=\d+\.\d{2}(?!\S))/\$/g` (oops, it's horrible i have two characters more.)

Comment: Re: "Are you sure it is always actual?" Yes. It can't be fixed. It's documented. `/p` and `${^MATCH}` was introduced as an alternative, but I don't see the point since you can just use `$1`

Comment: @ikegami: the goal was to avoid a capturing group that is slower too. Since you can replace `$&` by `${^MATCH}` (it's indeed in the documentation, I have found it.), I will replace `$&` by `${^MATCH}` in my first pattern.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, I have well understand the difference. However, using `${^MATCH}` or a capturing group don't have the same consequences than using `$&`. It is the reason why the second pattern is the fastest possible.

Comment: When you said "the goal", I thought you meant the goal of switching to `${^MATCH}`, I now see where you were going. Of course I know that avoid captures is fastest, seeing I posted the same thing 5 hours before you did :)